# groupby python formatting output

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am new to Python and learning a lot of new things everyday!.

I am running a group by code in pandas as follows and just noticed something interesting:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Hospital' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],"Claim Type" : ['HHA', 'HSP', 'IP', 'OP', 'SNF', 'DAE', 'CAR', 'HHA', 'HSP', 'IP', 'OP', 'SNF', 'DAE', 'CAR', 'HHA', 'HSP'],"avg spend" : [52, 12, 2, 80, 1, 7, 487, 14, 12, 7973, 54, 12, 20, 1549, 972, 169]})
df = df.groupby(['Hospital','Claim Type']).mean()[{'avg spend'}].round(2)

                      avg spend
Hospital Claim Type
A        HHA                52
         HSP                12
         IP                  2
         OP                 80
B        CAR               487
         DAE                 7
         HHA                14
         HSP                12
         IP               7973
         SNF                 1
C        CAR              1549
         DAE                20
         HHA               972
         HSP               169
         OP                 54
         SNF                12
```

when i enclose the column by which i aggregate(avg spend here), i get a formatted output (with banded rows) vs when i don't enclose it in curly brackets.

Just curious to know what happens here (in the  background probably) that formats the output.

Comment: Add some sample data and output that you find interesting to the question. And **No images** please.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'Hospital' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],"Claim Type" : ['HHA', 'HSP', 'IP', 'OP', 'SNF', 'DAE', 'CAR', 'HHA', 'HSP', 'IP', 'OP', 'SNF', 'DAE', 'CAR', 'HHA', 'HSP'],"avg spend" : [52, 12, 2, 80, 1, 7, 487, 14, 12, 7973, 54, 12, 20, 1549, 972, 169]})

Comment: Add those details to the question. You can [edit] from here.

Comment: output is same in both cases ,sorry dont know how to show without image, just that the output formats differently in both cases  , hence i am curious.

Comment: Edited your question. In this case `[{'avg spend'}]` output is dataframe , when `['avg spend']` output is Series. `[{'avg spend'}]` not the correct way instead use `[['avg spend']]` instead. ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you put this `[{'avg spend'}]` you are basically passing a `set` inside []. Like @Che3steR pointed out, you need to pass a list `[['avg spend']]`. They both give the same result:

```
df = df.groupby(['Hospital','Claim Type']).mean()[{'avg spend'}].round(2)
print(df)

                     avg spend
Hospital Claim Type
A        HHA                52
         HSP                12
         IP                  2
         OP                 80
B        CAR               487
         DAE                 7
         HHA                14
         HSP                12
         IP               7973
         SNF                 1
C        CAR              1549
         DAE                20
         HHA               972
         HSP               169
         OP                 54
         SNF                12

df = df.groupby(['Hospital','Claim Type']).mean()[['avg spend']].round(2)
print(df)

                     avg spend
Hospital Claim Type
A        HHA                52
         HSP                12
         IP                  2
         OP                 80
B        CAR               487
         DAE                 7
         HHA                14
         HSP                12
         IP               7973
         SNF                 1
C        CAR              1549
         DAE                20
         HHA               972
         HSP               169
         OP                 54
         SNF                12
```